# Why a share option is not available for a file?

Tags: files

After going through this help article ["Share Files with People in Lightning Experience"](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_files_sharing_people_lex.htm&type=5), I wanted to share a file with other users in my org. It appeared that there was not a `Share` option in the actions menu for the file.

[image]

Comment: Are you the owner of that file? I could be you need to own the file (or have collaborator rights yourself) in order to share it

Comment: Yes, I am the owner of that file. I just uploaded the file right before taking the screenshot.